# layer-list and ClipDrawable

Tags: java, android, layer-list

I have a problem with a simple piece, and I can't understand what is going wrong. What is the problem here? It should be simple.

I'm trying to do a 2-layer layer-list with one layer as a clip. Here is clip_source.xml which I made by instructions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item        

            android:drawable="@drawable/img_spare"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/clip">   
    <clip 
    android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
    android:drawable="@drawable/img_filled"
    android:gravity="left" />
    </item>
 </layer-list>
```

The Activity is simple :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        LayerDrawable ld= (LayerDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.clip_source);
        ClipDrawable cd=(ClipDrawable) ld.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.clip);

        cd.setLevel(4000);
        //((ClipDrawable) ld.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.clip)).setLevel(4000);
    img.setImageDrawable(ld);
    }
}
```

`cd.setLevel(4000)` (or if I try `getLevel()`) crashes everything with an unknown Exception. Is there a simple way to fix this?